# How can I use multidimensional arrays in PHP with MySQL-based sessions?

Tags: php, mysql, session, multidimensional-array

So I started using MySQL-based sessions with `session_module_name("user");` and I love it, and I might as well because I have to.

The only thing I'm missing are my beloved multidimensional arrays, and I'm at a juncture where they are most desired.  How can I still use them, or is it a lost cause?

Comment: What's the problem? AFAIK - You should be able to store multidimensional arrays in session stored in mySQL without problems.

Comment: Yeah I don't know, they just don't show up in the database and don't follow the state from page to page.  All my other variables work just fine... they usually look like this: count|i:13;user|s:1:"1";level|s:1:"2";theme|s:10:"fixeddream";

Comment: That's what they look like in the database, in case something looks wrong to you.

Comment: @aaron - could this bug by your problem:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33772

Comment: @cballou - I don't think so, but in all honesty, I don't completely understand everything mentioned there.  It looks to be about classes and __destruct, and I don't employ either, unless PHP is employing them behind the scenes.

Comment: @timdev - actually after a little tooling around it turns out you were right, they work anyway.  The problem was with my testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use seralize() method to convert your array data into a string representation (which is easily stored in a db). When you retrieve the data back from the db, use unseralize().